# Is there a way of only modifying Chinese characters through CSS (without affecting Roman characters)?

Tags: html, css, cjk

I noticed that Chinese characters tend to be a bit smaller in my website than Roman characters.

I would like to know if there's a way of modifying them through CSS without touching Roman characters.

For instance, assigning font-size to only Chinese characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically two options:

- Enforce server-side that all Chinese text, and only Chinese text, is wrapped in HTML elements labeled `lang="zh"`.  Then you can select them with `:lang(zh)` and apply a larger font-size.
- Use [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face) to load a Chinese font whose metrics more closely match the Roman font you are using.